How can I get around the error trying to use "oc rsync" by user?
Unable to use oc rsync and oc cp commands to copy files/directories by one user, while another one - successful.

Error: tar not available in container

Both users have access permissions:

oc auth can-i create pods/rsync - yes
oc auth can-i create pods/cp - yes

But only one account can perform operation with similar files.
I'm trying to use these commands:

oc login --server="<OKD_URL>" --username="<USER>" --password="<PASSWORD>" --kubeconfig="<FILE>" --insecure-skip-tls-verify -n "<NAMESPACE>"
oc cp ./directory/file <POD_NAME>:/directory --kubeconfig "<FILE>" -n "<NAMESPACE>"
oc rsync ./directory/file <POD_NAME>:/directory --strategy='tar' --kubeconfig "<FILE>" -n "<NAMESPACE>"

I'm expecting successful copying of files from local directory to pod.
Maybe there are another ways?

Both are trying the exact same commands to the same pods? It looks like both oc rsync and oc cp use tar in the pods (the former, it seems, maybe if the pod doesn't have rsync), and the error message seems to be saying that the pod doesn't have tar.
